# Getting aws cognito token in aws-amplify ui-react

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, nestjs, amazon-cognito

Im currently working in a Next.js frontend and NestJS backend application and im setting the login component with the @aws-amplify/ui-react:

like in the documentation
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';

import awsExports from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);

function App({ signOut, user }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

The problem is how can i get the jwt token and pass it to axios header?

```
    const response: any = await axios({
      method: method as Method,
      url: `http://localhost:3001/dev/${query}`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwtToken}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data,
    })
```

i`ve try to get the token from local storage but the key aways change because of the pool id and the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exact syntax about Next.js, but this is how I did in Angular (TypeScript).

#### ProfileComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { UserService } from "src/app/services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-profile",
  templateUrl: "./profile.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./profile.component.sass"],
})
export class ProfileComponent {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {

    Auth.currentSession().then((response) => {

      var idToken = response.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

      this.userService.getUserInfo(idToken).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

#### UserService.ts

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getUserInfo(accessToken: string): Observable<Weather[]> {

    var headers_object = new HttpHeaders().set("Authorization", "Bearer" + accessToken);

    return this.http.get<Weather[]>(
      "https://xxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/User",
      {
        headers: headers_object,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked!

just add this line:

     const token = (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken()

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Example PAM app. It uses a React app and uses Cognito to autheniate users.  This app does not use amplify. It uses React,  [Cloudscape Design System](https://cloudscape.design/), and the AWS SDK and makes requests to API Gateway endpoints:

[image]

As you can see in this illustration, the React app lets a user log in via a Cognito call. This app uses a token returned from Cognito. Once you understand that - you can apply it to your projects.

After you follow the instructions in this example, you get the full app which includes a login screen:

[image]

Once you log in - you see the app:

[image]

Look at the code in this example:

React code is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/resources/clients/react/elros-pam

Backend example is here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/usecases/pam_source_files