# How can I get AccessToken in my web app after I have authenticated with AWS Cognito?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an application that is secured behind AWS Cognito. So when you go to our site e.g. *foo.com* you first have to auth with your google credentials via cognito, after you do that you are redirected to our application.

Once there I want to be able to get access to who you are, aka your user email address, so that we can tailor your user experience to you. But I am having difficulty trying to determine how to extract the information I need. I know that I need the "AccessToken" so that I can make a call to the cognito api and ask for the information I need. But I don't know how to get that from the state I am in.

Looking at the local storage I do see "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0" and "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1" I am not sure if I should be using these? I know there must be a way to get the information I need. Someone please help! Thank you!

Comment: May help: https://repost.aws/questions/QUchj7dadVSKOOG38v7NX6Ow/trouble-getting-userinfo-from-id-token-in-cognito

Comment: What is type of your application where you want to get authenticated user's info? Is it ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core API, Express.JS, React or anything else?

Comment: @AnkushJain it's a react application

Comment: This is how I retrieved access token / ID Token in my Angular app. I was using Amplify SDK. Refer my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76290142/1273882